# How do I call a custom hook after success of another API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, msal-react

I have created a custom hook and a component:

```js
export const useUserInfo = () => {
  const query = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["users-info"],
    queryFn: () => fetchUserInfo(),
  });
  return query;
};

const Auth = () => {
  const { instance } = useMsal();

  const handleLoginPopup = async () => {
    try {
      const loginInfo = await instance.loginPopup(
        loginRequest,
      );

      const responseData = useUserInfo()
      console.log(responseData);

      navigate("/home");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
}
```

Here, I am trying to call the `useUserInfo` hook once the `loginPopup` request is success. But somehow, I am not able to do this as I am getting an error regarding the hooks which can not be called inside conditions. What can I try next?

Comment: You cannot put a hook call inside a function. They have to be top-level within the component definition. The following: `const responseData = useUserInfo()` is invalid usage of a hook.

Answer (score 0):

As the warning/error states you cannot call hooks inside plain functions. However you could move the hook call to the upper level (to the component's body) and use the `refetch` function to call the query in the `handleLoginPopup` function.

```
export const useUserInfo = () => {
  const query = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["users-info"],
    queryFn: () => fetchUserInfo(),
    enabled: false, // <-- disable fetch on mount
  });
  return query;
};

const Auth = () => {
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  const { refetch, data } = useUserInfo();

   const handleLoginPopup = async () => {
    try {
      const loginInfo = await instance.loginPopup(
        loginRequest,
      );

      await refetch(); // call the query
                       // you can await it so the data below will be up to date
      console.log(data);

      navigate("/home");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: But the thing is I have to call this hook only if the the first API is success.

Comment: @ganeshkaspate Just found in the docs that you can apparently disable calling the query on mount. So it will be called only on `refetch`. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

A good way in react / reactQuery is to use a useEffect hook to listen to the isSuccess propery from useQuery

```
export const useUserInfo = (isEnabled = false) => {
  const query = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["users-info"],
    queryFn: () => fetchUserInfo(),
    enabled: isEnabled
  });
  return query;
};

const Auth = () => {
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  const [isEnabledQuery, setIsEnabledQuery] = useState(false)
  const { refetch, data, isSuccess } = useUserInfo(isEnabledQuery);

  useEffect(() => { 
    // if login request is inside react query you could use the useEffect hook to trigger 
    // then you can destructure properties from useQuery for example isSuccess

    setIsEnabledQuery(isSuccess)
  }, [data, isSuccess])

   const handleLoginPopup = async () => {
    try {
      const loginInfo = await instance.loginPopup(
        loginRequest,
      );

      // login request is outside react query so manually check and set the isEnabled reactive variable
      setIsEnabledQuery(true)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
}
```

disclaimer: a gist not tested as a working example

disclaimer 2: IMO when a request chain starts getting lengthy it's often lighter to just handle things with the fetch api if you're on 4.x of react query it's buggy and in any version the boilerplate code can get silly sized.